# How do I clear placeholder text when using a ref in React Native?

Tags: react-native, textinput, ref

I have a TextInput component gets reused in a few different places:

```
export default class SomeTextInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        let fontWeight = this.props.fontWeight ? this.props.fontWeight : 'Light';
        let fontName = this.props.fontName ? this.props.fontName : 'Montserrat';
        let fontString = createFontString(fontName, fontWeight);
        let applyFontFamily = { fontFamily: fontString };
        let style = this.props.style.constructor === Array ? this.props.style : [this.props.style];
        return (
            <TextInput
                ref={(ref) => {
                    this.textInput = ref
                }}
                {...this.props}
                style={[applyFontFamily, ...style]}
                onFocus={() => {
                    this.clearText();
                    console.log('show me this.textInput', this.textInput.props.placeholder)

                }}
            />
        )
    }
    clearText() {
        this.textInput.clear();
        console.log('is this being reached???')
    }
    focus() {
        this.textInput.focus();
    }
    blur() {
        this.textInput.blur();
    }
}
```

I've also tried using `clearTextOnFocus`. I believe the best way to do this would be to change the `placeholder` to `''`, but I'm not sure how given that the `placeholder` text is taken from a `prop` that's been passed down.

edit:  I'm going to add the code that @ravibagul91 suggested

```
export default class OVTextInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // this.state = {
        //     placeholder: props.placeholder
        // }
    }
    render() {
        let fontWeight = this.props.fontWeight ? this.props.fontWeight : 'Light';
        let fontName = this.props.fontName ? this.props.fontName : 'Montserrat';
        let fontString = createFontString(fontName, fontWeight);
        let applyFontFamily = { fontFamily: fontString };
        let style = this.props.style.constructor === Array ? this.props.style : [this.props.style];
        return (
            <TextInput
                ref={(ref) => {
                    this.textInput = ref
                }}
                {...this.props}
                style={[applyFontFamily, ...style]}
                onFocus={() => {
                    // this.setState({ placeholder: "" });
                    this.clearText();

                }}
            />
        )
    }

    clearText = () => {
        console.log(this.textInput)
        console.log('is this being reached???', this.textInput.value);
        console.log('is this being reached???', this.textInput.placeholder);
        this.textInput.placeholder = "";
        this.textInput.value = "";

    }
    //   focus = () => {
    //         this.textInput.focus();
    //     }
    //     blur = () => {
    //         this.textInput.blur();
    //     }
    focus() {
        this.textInput.focus();
    }
    blur() {
        this.textInput.blur();
    }
};
```

Comment: You mean you want to erase the placeholder, not the text?

Comment: I want to the placeholder text to disappear when the input is focused.  Currently, the text only disappears when I begin typing

Comment: @VK1 Also try my solution, and let me know if that helps.

Comment: I tried your solution.  Both this.textInput.value and this.texInput.placeholder came back as undefined in the console.logs

Comment: Have you passed them as props? See my Demo, I have passed value and placeholder as props. If you don't want to pass then you can directly write placeholder manually.

Comment: I'm going to update my original post with the code that I used to try your solution

Comment: I was in a impression that `{...this.props}` giving you the placeholder. Check my Demo again I have updated the same.

Comment: Other than adding {...this.props} in the placeholder as props version and then adding placeholder{'manual placeholder'} I don't see a difference.  It seems like this.textInput.placeholder can't be updated

Comment: Adding placeholder in two ways don't make any difference (I have added for sake of simplicity), but in demo you can see that doing `this.textInput.placeholder = ""` is clearing the placeholder, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are currently doing is erasing the value of the `text`. Your `Textinput` looks like a prop for receiving and using values. `Textinput` does not currently have the ability to clear `placeholders`. If you make a proposal, you can use the `status values` to solve it.

```js
export default class SomeTextInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
           placeholder: props.placeholder
        }
    }
....
            <TextInput
                ref={(ref) => {
                    this.textInput = ref
                }}
                placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
                {...this.props}
                style={[applyFontFamily, ...style]}
                onFocus={() => {
                    this.setState({ placeholder : "" });
                    console.log('show me placeholder', this.state.placeholder)

                }}
            />
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly clear the `placeholder` like,

```
this.textInput.placeholder = "";
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xpdgir)

**Note:** This is tested simply on `input` but same will work for `TextInput`.